# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.eith react.js,webpack,babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to compile  js file with react using webpack with babel, but I am getting the following error message:

ERROR in ./js/IntroAndWorkSpace.js
Module parse failed: C:\FULLTIME\STUDY METERIAL\ReactJS\NewReactPoject\js\IntroAndWorkSpace.js Unexpected token (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:8)

here is my js file

```js
import* React from 'react'
import*  ReactDOM from 'react-dom',


ReactDOM.render(<h1>headingthe  of page</h1>,
 document.getElementById('head')
 );
```

here is pakeje.json

```js
{
  "name": "newreactproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myreactproject for learning react",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "priya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  }
}
```

here is config.js

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/scripts.js",
     loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/js",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: I haven't seen `import*` before, you probably just want `import React from 'react'` ? Also the comma at the end of this line is invalid `import*  ReactDOM from 'react-dom',`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything set up correctly.  I believe the problem is that your webpack configuration file is configured to load files with the extension `.jsx` with the `babel` loader using the `react` and `ES2015` presets, but the file you're attempting to load (IntroAndWorkSpace.js) doesn't end with the `.jsx` extension.

Since it's probably a good idea to be consistent with your file extensions, you have two options for fixing this:

1) Change the extension of the file you're trying to load to `.js` instead of `.jsx`.

2) Change the loader test to load files with the extension `.js` instead of `.jsx`:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        ...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
              plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
            }
          }
        ],
```